# how to solve the question "Couldn't match expected type ‘b1’ with actual type ‘b’"

Tags: haskell

I have faced a problem when I am working with a function :

```
plotDensity :: Forest -> ([Site] -> a -> b) -> a -> Int -> [(Int, b)]
```

Forest is a data that has a type : `Forest = Forest Int Int [Site]`

To answer the question, I type codes like :

```
plotDensity :: Forest -> ([Site] -> a -> b) -> a -> Int -> [(Int, b)]
plotDensity forest densityFunc densityArg n
  | n < 0 = error "Invalid input: n should be a non-negative integer."
  | otherwise = [(day, treeDensity day) | day <- [0 .. n]]
  where
    treeDensity :: Int -> b
    treeDensity day = callDensityFunc (sitesAfterNDays day) densityArg

    callDensityFunc :: [Site] -> a -> b
    callDensityFunc sites arg = densityFunc sites arg

    sitesAfterNDays :: Int -> [Site]
    sitesAfterNDays day = case day of
      0 -> getSites forest
      _ -> getSites (iterate updateForest forest !! day)

    -- Helper function to get the sites from the Forest data type
    getSites :: Forest -> [Site]
    getSites (Forest _ _ sites) = sites
```

This function aims to form a list of tuples for another Codeworld function to generate a density plot. But I always got an error called:

```
src\ForestFire.hs:185:33: error:
    ? Couldn't match expected type ‘b1’ with actual type ‘b’
      ‘b1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          callDensityFunc :: forall a1 b1. [Site] -> a1 -> b1
        at src\ForestFire.hs:184:5-39
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          plotDensity :: forall a b.
                         Forest -> ([Site] -> a -> b) -> a -> Int -> [(Int, b)]
        at src\ForestFire.hs:176:1-69
    ? In the expression: densityFunc sites arg
      In an equation for ‘callDensityFunc’:
          callDensityFunc sites arg = densityFunc sites arg
      In an equation for ‘plotDensity’:
          plotDensity forest densityFunc densityArg n
            | n < 0
            = error "Invalid input: n should be a non-negative integer."
            | otherwise = [(day, treeDensity day) | day <- [0 .. n]]
            where
                treeDensity :: Int -> b
                treeDensity day = callDensityFunc (sitesAfterNDays day) densityArg
                callDensityFunc :: [Site] -> a -> b
                callDensityFunc sites arg = densityFunc sites arg
                ....
    ? Relevant bindings include
        callDensityFunc :: [Site] -> a1 -> b1
          (bound at src\ForestFire.hs:185:5)
        densityFunc :: [Site] -> a -> b (bound at src\ForestFire.hs:177:20)
        plotDensity :: Forest
                       -> ([Site] -> a -> b) -> a -> Int -> [(Int, b)]
          (bound at src\ForestFire.hs:177:1)
    |
185 |     callDensityFunc sites arg = densityFunc sites arg
    |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src\ForestFire.hs:185:51: error:
    ? Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘a1’
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          callDensityFunc :: forall a1 b1. [Site] -> a1 -> b1
        at src\ForestFire.hs:184:5-39
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          plotDensity :: forall a b.
                         Forest -> ([Site] -> a -> b) -> a -> Int -> [(Int, b)]
        at src\ForestFire.hs:176:1-69
    ? In the second argument of ‘densityFunc’, namely ‘arg’
      In the expression: densityFunc sites arg
      In an equation for ‘callDensityFunc’:
          callDensityFunc sites arg = densityFunc sites arg
    ? Relevant bindings include
        arg :: a1 (bound at src\ForestFire.hs:185:27)
        callDensityFunc :: [Site] -> a1 -> b1
          (bound at src\ForestFire.hs:185:5)
        densityArg :: a (bound at src\ForestFire.hs:177:32)
        densityFunc :: [Site] -> a -> b (bound at src\ForestFire.hs:177:20)
        plotDensity :: Forest
                       -> ([Site] -> a -> b) -> a -> Int -> [(Int, b)]
          (bound at src\ForestFire.hs:177:1)
    |

185 |     callDensityFunc sites arg = densityFunc sites arg
```

I want to make it pass the cabal v2-test, why does this happen? How can I solve that?

I think a and b are polymorphic and should contain INt and Double. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the type variables `a` and `b` from your local signature:

```
    callDensityFunc :: [Site] -> a -> b
```

are treated as being different than the variables `a` and `b` in your top level signature:

```
plotDensity :: Forest -> ([Site] -> a -> b) -> a -> Int -> [(Int, b)]
```

In general, you can solve this by enabling the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension and adding a `forall` in the top level type signature:

```
plotDensity :: forall a b. Forest -> ([Site] -> a -> b) -> a -> Int -> [(Int, b)]
```

In your case you can also solve it by removing the local type signature as it can be inferred. You'll also have to remove the local type signature of `treeDensity`.